# Where is Ubuntu-tweak?

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I have a netbook and I need to clean it, I got odkas on ubuntu-tweak, and skousela be installed by navodu. Ale unfortunately I have not found it nor the software for Ubuntu, though here it skousela look so show me dostupny. Jako not from there at all neni. Prosim advice about how accurate the description should he do it so I could nainstalovat. A Please can I come up with some error about everything in the computer mam?

<sub>[Original post in Czech](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/312170/1)</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is an English-only site. Please keep your post in English.

Answer (score 2):

Ubutnu Tweak can be found at http://ubuntu-tweak.com/. Download the file and then click. It installs itself Center software.

Yes, by careless handling can damage the system ;-)